# Turning a python function to an AWS Lambda handler in boto

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am working on AWS Lambda function for my python function. I have a python function that calls an IAM policy form a file and populates it using the function. This is my function, name of the file is template_utils.py":

```
import sys
import json
import time 
import meta_templates
from jinja2 import Template
def lambda_handler(event,context):
  template_data = {}
  template_data["region"] = event.get('region')
  template_data["instance_types"] = event.get('instance_type')
  template_data["ebs_volume_size"] = event.get('ebs_volume_size')
  template_data["meta_template_name"] = event.get('meta_template_name')

  meta_template_dict = getattr(meta_templates, template_data["meta_template_name"])
  meta_template_json = json.dumps(meta_template_dict)
  template_json = Template(meta_template_json).render(template_data)
  return template_json  

template_json = lambda_handler(
  region="us-east-2",
  instance_type="t2.micro",
  ebs_volume_size="20",
  meta_template_name="ec2_policy_meta_template"
)

print(template_json)
```

This is my policy file named "meta_templates.py"

```
import json
from jinja2 import Template
ec2_policy_meta_template = { 
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::instance/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::network-interface/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::key-pair/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::security-group/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::subnet/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::volume/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::image/ami-*"
                ],
                "Condition": {
                    "ForAllValues:NumericLessThanEquals": {
                        "ec2:VolumeSize": "{{ebs_volume_size}}"
                    },
                    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                        "ec2:InstanceType": "{{instance_type}}"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                    "ec2:StartInstances",
                    "ec2:StopInstances"
                ],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::instance/*",
                "Condition": {
                    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                        "ec2:InstanceType": "{{instance_type}}"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:Describe*",
                    "ec2:GetConsole*",
                    "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                    "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
                    "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                    "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                    "ec2:CreateKeyPair"
                ],
                "Resource": "*",
                "Condition": {
                    "DateGreaterThan": {
                        "aws:CurrentTime": "{{start_time}}"
                    },
                    "DateLessThanEquals": {
                        "aws:CurrentTime": "{{end_time}}"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want to create a lambda handler that does the same thing with the function "template_utils.py".I'm new to this not sure how to proceed with it.

Comment: If you want to deploy multiple Python modules, then package them up in a ZIP file and deploy [per the instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html).

Comment: I actually want to do it using Boto

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can happily use boto3 to upload Lambda functions, but if you want multiple Python modules then you're still going to have to package them, however you choose to do that.